# Do fury effects work during group fury?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island Riptide, a new group fury option has been introduced. It is unlocked by putting at least one point in the appropriate skill in the middle of the Fury skill tree. Group fury is activated by pressing the Fury button again before hitting anything in Fury.

Some Fury skills affect you while you're in Fury, but it is unclear whether or not that they still apply if one activates group fury. Do fury effects work during group fury?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing than I expected to be required, the answer is no.
The definitive answer came when I checked how group fury was affected by Xian Mei's Assassin's Guile which boosts her maximum health when she furies. When she group furies, the max health bonus is removed. I'd add video, but I'm not happy with the recording that I took.

If you prefer to group fury over regular fury, stay away from skills that affect fury mode.